# stub test cases are not showing in code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, spock

I am doing my unit testing using spock framework. I am using stub to do my test. my unit test gave me success but when I checked my code coverage that is showing that code has not been included. Is it expected behaviour? if not how to resolve this?

below is my spcok framework code

```
  class ConfigurationLoaderTest extends Specification {
    def "loadConfigurationTest" (){
        given:
        ConfigurationLoader configLoader = Stub()
        when:
        def rpcApiInfo= configLoader.loadConfiguration();
        then:
        rpcApiInfo != null
    }
    }
```

when I ran it it showing test case passed but my code coverage is still 0 for 'loadConfiguration' method

Comment: Why should the code count as covered if you are using a `Stub` you are not testing anything with it?

Comment: Then how should I mock it??

Comment: you shouldn't if you want to test your code. You only mock/stub dependencies of your system under test and not the system itself.

Comment: Okay..I was trying to implement how I used to do with mockito in java. because in my case I download file of 350 mb so I wanted to avoid that

Comment: Maybe you could share the code of `ConfigurationLoader`